# unable to deserialize the object of type DialogManager(Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs)

Tags: c#, json.net, botframework

```
private void LoadRootDialogAsync()
{
    var rootFile = this.resourceExplorer.GetResource("Main.dialog");
    this.rootDialog = DeclarativeTypeLoader.Load<AdaptiveDialog>(rootFile, this.resourceExplorer, this.sourceMap);
    this.dialogManager = new DialogManager(this.rootDialog);
}
string dm = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.dialogManager);
DialogManager dialogManager = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DialogManager>(dm);
```

but when i am trying to deserialize it, it is throwing

> Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Dialog. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

Please look into this

Comment: please post the code for the type `DialogManager`

Comment: DialogManager is Assembly created class by installing the following nudget **Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs**.
Here I will attach the meta class of DialogManager class in below comment

Comment: `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs
{
    public class DialogManager
    {
        public DialogManager(Dialog rootDialog = null);
        public int? ExpireAfter { get; set; }
        [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<OnTurnAsync>d__12))]
        public Task<DialogManagerResult> OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
    }
}`

Comment: @MongZhu please look into this

Comment: please edit your post there is an [edit Button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59983508/edit) below your post, click it and add the code, it is unreadable in the comment

Comment: (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will have to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.) Is this your issue? https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/3301

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost certainly going about this the wrong way, which I will address in the linked GitHub issue, but since we're here I will answer the question you asked.

The JSON you're serializing does not contain enough information for Newtonsoft to know how to deserialize it. You're telling `JsonConvert` to deserialize that JSON as a `DialogManager`, and it sees that the `RootDialog` property is of the abstract type `Dialog`. Since it doesn't know what type of dialog the property contains, there's no way for it to be deserialized.

In order to get Newtonsoft to deserialize your `DialogManager` correctly, you must first serialize it correctly. You can do this by serializing it with type-name handling information.

```
var rootDialog = new WaterfallDialog("waterfall", new List<WaterfallStep>
{
    async (stepContext, cancellationToken) => await stepContext.EndDialogAsync()
});

var dm = new DialogManager(rootDialog);

var jss = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dm, Formatting.Indented, jss);

Console.WriteLine(json);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DialogManager>(json, jss));
```

However, you will notice that the serialized waterfall dialog in this example contains only the ID and not the steps, so it still doesn't get serialized with all the information you need. This is because dialogs in the v4 SDK aren't meant to be serialized into JSON, and so you can't depend on JSON to contain all the information a dialog needs to work. You're probably going to need to find another way to do what you're trying to do by following instructions and samples about how adaptive dialogs are supposed to be used. Fortunately, there is a JSON schema that can be used to represent adaptive dialogs, so you might want to look into declarative dialogs.